# How is phenolic resin made?

Tags: phenols

The following chemical structure is phenolic resin.  How is this chemical made?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an experiment that all my students have carried out in the lab.

Make a solution with about $3$ mL $40$% solution of methanal and an equal volume of phenol. Transfer the solution into a small paper cup. Add a equal volume of concentrated $\ce{HCl}$, when stirring with a glas rod. This produces a strong exothermic reaction, and the result is the described phenolic resin, whose common name is bakelite.

Comment: The phenolic resin called [bakelite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite) is rather a 
phenolformaldehyde resin.

Comment: My synthesis is producing a phenol formaldehyde resin, as methanal is also called formaldehyde,

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You have initially written methanol, what is understandable as easily done typo. More exactly, it would be rather 40%(probably) solution of methanal, which is itself gaseous.